# Making a Backbone.js view to draw objects on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, backbone.js

I am making an application where different rectangles are painted on a canvas and I am trying to do it with Backbone. I have a model called box:

```
    Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: 1,
            h: 1,
            color: "#FF9000",
            linewidth: 3,
            id: 0,
        },

        drawBox: function(ctx) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9000";
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
            ctx.fillRect(this.get("x"), this.get("y"), this.get("w"), this.get("h")); //transparent box in the back
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.get("color");
            ctx.lineWidth = this.get("linewidth");
            ctx.strokeRect(this.get("x"), this.get("y"), this.get("w"), this.get("h")); //rectangle on top      
        }
    });
```

And I also have a collection of this Box model:

```
    BoxSet = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Box          
    });
```

What I have in mind is to have a view where I can put every Box model in the BoxSet collection on a canvas using the drawBox method in the Box model, but so far all the tutorials and examples deal with simple text templates and I cannot figure out how to acomplish this.

Any ideas on how could this be done using Backbone views?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would follow the separation of models and views offered by Backbone. Keep your models as data repositories :

```
var Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: 1,
        h: 1,
        color: "#FF9000",
        linewidth: 3
        // don't define a default id, that leads to strange behaviors
    }
});

var BoxSet = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Box
});
```

And define the views to render the different pieces on a canvas:

```
var BoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var model = this.model, ctx = this.options.ctx;

        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9000";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
        ctx.fillRect(
            model.get("x"), model.get("y"),
            model.get("w"), model.get("h")
        ); 

        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = model.get("color");
        ctx.lineWidth = model.get("linewidth");
        ctx.strokeRect(
            model.get("x"), model.get("y"), 
            model.get("w"), model.get("h")
        );
    }
});

var SetView= Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "all", this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        var canvas = this.el, ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var view = new BoxView({ctx: ctx, model: model});
            view.render();
        })
    }
});
```

And finally instantiate and render:

```
var c = new BoxSet();
c.add({x: 150, y: 150, w: 100, h: 100});
c.add({x: 10, y: 10, w: 100, h: 100});

var v = new SetView({
    el: $("canvas"),
    collection : c
});
v.render();
```

A Fiddle to view those two nice squares http://jsfiddle.net/JB9yg/

Another one where a change to the collection leads to re-rendering http://jsfiddle.net/JB9yg/1/

This example can probably be built upon to provide cleaner manipulations, but that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr, this is a great solution. It gives me more control over the squares and makes it more flexible to make further modifications.

Comment: Any ideas on how to make the SetView paint or erase a box from the canvas everytime one gets added/removed from the collection?

Comment: @rpabon I added a possible solution where everything gets redrawn. It could be interesting to check if a set of instructions can be defined as an object and manipulated independently on a canvas.

Comment: Thanks @nikoshr. I did the same before asking, but not with "all" but with "add"/"push" and "pop"/"remove" and it did not work. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @rpabon Listening to `add` and `remove` events works too, see http://jsfiddle.net/JB9yg/2/ Maybe a missing `this` on the binding?

Answer (score 2):

Also you may try to use [Backbone.KineticView](https://github.com/slash-system/backbone.kineticview) plugin to add canvas support to Backbone.
It works via KineticJS, so may also use all power of event delegation for canvas nodes.

Example:

```
var MyView = Backbone.KineticView.extend({
  // build Kineticjs object, then return it.
  el : function(){
    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x : 100,
      y : 100,
      width : 50,
      height : 50,
      fill : 'green',
      id : 'rect'
    });
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
      x : 200,
      y : 100,
      radius : 50,
      fill : 'red',
      name : 'circle'
    });
    var group = new Kinetic.Group();
    group.add(rect).add(circle);
    return group;
  },
  // setup events
  events : {
    'click #rect' : function(){
      console.log("on rectangle clicked");
    },
    'mouseover .circle' : 'onMouseOverCircle'
  },
  onMouseOverCircle : function(){
    console.log('Mouse is over circle');
  },
  render : function(){
    // this.$el - cached kineticjs object.
    this.options.layer.add(this.$el);
    layer.draw();
  }
});

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container : 'container',
  width : 300,
  height : 300
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

view = new MyView({layer:layer});
view.render();
```