# Unsure of where to declare 2D context variable in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, canvas

I'm just getting started learning Backbone, and thought I'd try create a simple drawing application using the `canvas` element. Problem is, I'm not sure where, in the view, I should declare the 2D context object (if that's where I should declare it at all)?

**[I have a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlowgren/QFgpc/)**, though it currently doesn't function. It does work on my local development environment though.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716478/making-a-backbone-js-view-to-draw-objects-on-a-canvas/10717534#10717534 ?

Comment: You're using old versions of Backbone (0.3.3) and Underscore (1.1.4); you'll have a better time if you use the latest versions (0.9.10 and 1.4.4): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KJyHD/